# Tapestry javascript deferredZoneUpdate method of zoneManager callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback, fullcalendar, tapestry

I make a [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) in my [tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/) 5.4 web page.

When I make a new [Event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) or I click an existing event, the fullcalendar's method is called (`select` or `eventClick`). In these methods tapestry js method is called (`zoneManager.deferredZoneUpdate("formZone", listenerURIWithValue);`), because I want to refresh my jQuery dialog div (`#formZone`) what is a tapestry zone. And it works well functionally, the data appears.

However, I always see the refreshing "procedure" because after the zone-update part, the jQuery dialog is opened, but the refresh is not ending (I know because ajax call is asynchronous) and it causes an "ugly" refresh after the jQuery dialog is opened.

**My goal** is to define a callback function for `deferredZoneUpdate` or make this code sequence:

```
...
zoneManager.deferredZoneUpdate("formZone", listenerURIWithValue);
$('#wsDialog').dialog('open');
...
```

Thanks for the answers in advance!

**Update:**

calendar-init.js:

```
    define(["jquery" , "t5/core/zone"], function($, zoneManager) {
        return function(modifyEventLink, newEventLink, pageTurnLink, allDayText) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var calendarDiv = $('#calendar');
                calendarDiv.fullCalendar({
                 //....init
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {


                // create modifyeventlink with id param
                var listenerURIWithValue = appendQueryStringParameter(modifyEventLink, 'eventID', calEvent.id);
                // ajax zone update
                zoneManager.deferredZoneUpdate("formZone", listenerURIWithValue);
                // open the worksheet dialog
                $('#wsDialog').dialog('option', 'title', calEvent.title);
            },
            //...init
   });});}}) // the code syntacs is good dont bother these :D
```

backend:

```
void onModifyEventLink() {
    if(request.isXHR()) {
        logger.debug("ModifyEventLink on.");
        String eventID = (String) request.getParameter("eventID");
        if(eventID == null) {
            logger.error("wsDialog was not able to load because eventID is NULL!");
        } else {                
            try{
                wSheet = sheetService.find(Integer.valueOf(eventID));
                if(wSheet != null) {    
                    ajaxResponseRenderer
                        .addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {
                            javascriptSupport.require("wsdialogs");
                            }};)
                        .addRender(formZone);
                } else {
                    logger.warn("Worksheet with " + eventID + " not found.");                   
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                logger.error("wsDialog was not able to load beacause eventID was not a number.");
                logger.error("Exception: ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    } else {
        logger.debug("ModifyEventLink on, request is not XHR (ajax)");
    }
}
```

(module) wsdialogs.js:

```
define(["jquery" , "t5/core/zone"], function($, zoneManager) {
        console.log("wsdialog-js run"); 
        $("#wsDialog").dialog('open');
});
```

tml:

```
<t:container
   xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_4.xsd"
   xmlns:p="tapestry:parameter">

   <t:jquery.dialog t:clientId="wsDialog" t:id="wsDialog" title="${message:wsheet-new}" style="display: none;">
      <t:zone t:id="formZone" id="formZone">
        <t:form t:id="worksheetForm" t:type="form" t:zone="^">
            ....
        </t:form>   
       </t:zone> 
    </t:jquery.dialog>
</t:container>
```

Comment: Why not to open dialog in listenerURIWithValue callback?

Comment: because that way I can define the Zone, and the url. But listenerURIWithValue method can handle callback function or is a synchronous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ComponentWithZone {
    @Inject
    private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;        
    ...
    public void onSomeEventFromClient() {
        ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender("zone-id-to-update", zone.getBody()).addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {
            @Override
            public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {
                javascriptSupport.require("modal").invoke("showModal").with("#dialog-id");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This example is with bootstrap modal included as tapestry module.

When tapestry refresh zone div with content it will trigger showModal function.

UPD: Forgot to mention that this example assumes that you have modal module.
Here is example of mine:

```
(function(){
    define(["jquery", "bootstrap/modal"], function($, modal) {
        return {
            showModal: function(id) {
                $('#'+id).modal('show');
            },
            hideModal: function(id) {
                $('#'+id).modal('hide');
            }
        };
    });
}).call(this);
```

Instead of *bootstrap/modal* you can use any module, but don't forget to include it in META-INF/modules.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not works.. I got the ajaxresponse but an error comes up in the console `GET 
http://localhost:8080/webpage/modules.gz/modal.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 84ms]
"RequireJS error: scripterror: Script error for: modal
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror, modules modal"`

I had an idea, what if I made my own module (what includes the opening `$("#wsDialog").dialog('open');`), and that will be open my dialog, In the first time works well, but after that (I tried many times) my module does not run.

Comment: Yep, forgot to mention modal module. See upd.

Comment: I make a META-INF/modules/wsdialogs.js  `define(["jquery" , "t5/core/zone"], function($, zoneManager) {
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log("wsdialog-js run");
  $("#wsDialog").dialog('open');
 }); });`
and after that a make this: 
`ajaxResponseRenderer
 .addCallback(new JavaScriptCallback() {
   @Override
   public void run(JavaScriptSupport javascriptSupport) {
    javascriptSupport.require("wsdialogs");
   }
  };)
 .addRender(formZone);`
And it couse that i have written. First time appear the dialog but after that it does not.

Comment: So the problem because I use jquery dialog instead of (your) bootstrap?

Comment: You're binding to $( document ).ready event which triggers once, not each time you call zone update.

Comment: Ohh rookie mistake.. But still not works:
First try, META-INF/modules/wsdialogs.js `(function(){
 define(["jquery" , "t5/core/zone"], function($, zoneManager) {
   console.log("wsdialog-js run");
   $("#wsDialog").dialog('open');
 });
}).call(this);`
Second try, META-INF/modules/wsdialogs.js 
`define(["jquery" , "t5/core/zone"], function($, zoneManager) {
  console.log("wsdialog-js run");
  $("#wsDialog").dialog('open');
});`

But the result is the same. Honestly Im just a rookie with this tapestry..

Comment: Things become complicated :) Do you have you code somewhere in public (github, bitbucket)?

Comment: unfortunately It is forbidden to share the whole code, because the code is not mine, it belongs to the company what I works for, But I will append some code to the question. And thank you again in adcance.

Comment: I figured out the problem:
My module was not good semantically. Thanks a lot.